# ogr2ogr importing geojson into PostgreSQL Error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, ubuntu

Having read everywhere as to the cause of these errors I'm at a loss. Trying to import geojson Point data into a new PostgreSQL database with the POSTGIS extension enabled.

1. PostgreSQL-9.4.17
2. Postgis 2.4.3
3. GDAL 1.10.1
4. Ubuntu 14.04
5. I've edited my pg_hba.conf to "trust"
6. I've created a table, granted all permissions, created password for superuser postgres. I'm able to import other SQL files
7. Edited permissions on the geojson file I want to import
8. GeoJSON is valid

The issue comes when I try to import a geojson file using ogr2ogr

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=dbname user=postgres" "file.geosjon" -nln tableName
```

And all i get in response is:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Using pgadmin if I inspect the table it imports all the correct column headers but no actual data.

I'm thinking its a permission issue or version issue after reading [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195172/import-a-shapefile-to-postgis-with-ogr2ogr-gives-unable-to-open-datasource) .

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the geojson wasn't formatted properly. Had empty arrays as property values...really wish gdal and ogr2ogr had better documentation or error logging. Oh well.

Comment: GDAL should never crash. Please create a ticket at https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ and attach some faulty GeoJSON data. Alternatively you can write mail to gdal-dev mailing list.

Comment: Will do when I get the chance